# iPad UI navigation - split view with horizontally scrolling views

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, navigation

I'm looking for suggestions to implement a specific UI navigation pattern on iPad. It's not radically different from standard behaviour, but I'm unsure of the best approach to use.

Picture a standard split view, with a master view on the left, detail on the right. I want an action in the detail view (e.g. button press) to navigate to an additional detail screen by scrolling from right to left. The result is that the original detail view is on the left (with its width unchanged), and the new detail view on the right. A back button in the nav bar reverses the process. When the master view is visible, the back button is replaced by a menu button in the nav bar (show/hide slide out menu).

I've seen a few similar implementations in existing apps. One that's easy to reference is Shopify's 
[online demo](http://www.shopify.com/pos/demo/). Adding an item to the cart and pressing the total button triggers the navigation behaviour.

Any pointers on the best way to implement this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to do something complicated with split view controllers, try this instead. Make a single view controller with a view that contains all 3 view (master, detail, and second detail), which is wider than the screen so that the second detail is not visible. When you want to show the second detail, animate the top-level view to the left to show it; when the back button is hit, animate it back to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After a bit more research, I'm looking at using a custom container view to achieve this, as it seems to be the 'official' way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom container view was a good solution.